# HAML fails to properly parse my Ruby code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I'm using [HAML](https://github.com/haml/haml), and the following code works:

```
content = '= User.last.name' #last.name = 'joe'
Haml::Engine.new(content).render >> joe
```

Why does HAML correctly parse that string, but fails to correctly parse the following string?

```
 content = '= User.last.name 
              %title
                  html2haml and multiline titles'

 Haml::Engine.xxxx(content) >> "= User.last.name
                                 <title>
                                   html2haml and multiline titles
                                 </title>"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me if you're typing it in verbatim as above, which I think would lead to indentation issues.

Consider a herestring:

```
content = <<EOS
= User.last.name 
  %title
    html2haml and multiline titles
EOS
```

My guess is your string has indentation issues; the above works fine.

<sup>(There's a [`strip_heredoc` in Rails 3](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b422cda2ebfff4032f4c18271e96ad329c413dcc/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/strip.rb) so you can indent the herestring, which reads easier in the source.)</sup>